# The appropriate way to build a registration form in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, registration

I just started studying Drupal 7 and learned how powerful CCK and Views are. But it still confuses me a bit because it behaves so differently compared to Wordpress. Now I want to build registration form, is it appropriate to build it using CCK? If so, how do I make it so it would make the login system aware that a new user has registered? Or would it be better and easier to modify the built-in registration system to my liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A registration form for... what exactly? The site? An event? RSVP? If this is just to register and post comments or blog articles, then use the core login system- thats what it's there for. You can add fields to this form by enabling Profile module and adding fields to capture more data about the user.